# Modify Http Request

Tags: javascript, jquery, flash

I want to modify a request send from flash using java-script. or the second approach can be want to monitor window.location change and block it.

Please let me know how i can do it any one of the approach.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you add more detail to your question?  Right now it's hard to understand exactly what you were having trouble with, which makes it less helpful for future users.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved it. we can prevent navigation on window.onbeforeunload. Just added an event listener and match with which link is about to open and resolved it. It saves lots of time.

Comment: If possible can you add a code snippet that solved your problem?  This will make it much more helpful to future users.